# Conditional Statement if no value exists in PHP or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, conditional-statements

I created an unordered list with the following html:

```
<ul id="infoBox">
         <li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo get_field('facebook_page'); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> on Facebook</a></li>
         <li class="twitter"><a href="<?php echo get_field('twitter_page'); ?>">Follow <?php the_title(); ?> on Twitter</a></li>
         <li class="youtube"><a href="<?php echo get_field('youtube_page'); ?>">Watch <?php the_title(); ?> on Youtube</a></li>
 </ul>
```

`<?php echo get_field('value'); ?>` is grabbing a string from the backend of my site. Sometimes, I do not have a string to display, so I want to create a conditional statement in jquery and/or php that basically says: **If  there is no field to get** (if the field is left empty on the backend), **do not display the list item at all.** For instance, if a band doesn't have a youtube page, do not display the list item with a class of 'youtube' at all.

Any idea how I would go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul id="infoBox">
    <?php $response = get_field('facebook_page'); 
    if(!empty($response)): ?><li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo $response; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> on Facebook</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php $response = get_field('twitter_page');
    if(!empty($response)): ?><li class="twitter"><a href="<?php echo $response; ?>">Follow <?php the_title(); ?> on Twitter</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php $response = get_field('youtube_page');
    if(!empty($response)): ?><li class="youtube"><a href="<?php echo $response; ?>">Watch <?php the_title(); ?> on Youtube</a></li><?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: no, it returns an error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Comment: I really like this type of solution, but I am still getting a syntax error on these lines: <?php if(!empty($response): ?><li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo $response; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> on Facebook</a></li><?php endif; ?>

Comment: @jchase11, ohh, woops, typo. Fixed. Check now, should be perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(get_field('value') == '' || is_null(get_field('value')) 
   echo 'no value';
else
   echo 'there is a value';
```

I hope understand your question and could help.

Comment: Im not seeing how I can use this, can you please elaborate? I need to apply this rule for all of the list items, so if a band doesnt have either a youtube, twitter, or fb page, the list item will not display.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id='infoBox'>
<?php
    $name = the_title();
    $potentialItems = array('facebook' => "$name on facebook", 
                            'youtube' => "Watch $name on youtube", 
                            'twitter' =? "Follow $name on twitter");

   foreach($potentialItems as $k=>$v)
   {
        $gf = get_field($k.'_page');
        if($gf)
        {
            echo "<li class='$k'><a href='$gf'>$v</a></li>";
        }
   }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow quite the php solution. I cant get this to work currently, let me mess with it for awhile. Thanks for your help. Is all the syntax correct here?

Comment: mo, i messed up the clause inside the for loop. `$potenitalItems as $k=$v)` should be `$potenitalItems as $k=>$v)` and I have corrected it. I am also trusting your `the_title()` and `get_field` functions even tho i dont know anything about them. as you can see, this should make it extensibnle and real easy to add new kinds of items

Comment: jc - as you can see i dont really like stepping into/out of PHP lots of times back and forth.  hence the larger code block and the use of echo